# WPF App looks different on Windows 8 and Windows 7

Tags: wpf, windows

I have just started using WPF. The problem I'm having is the elements look different on Windows 8.1 (where it was developed) and the Windows 7 machine (client).

[Windows 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3fOF.jpg)
[Windows 8.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc9i6.jpg)

The buttons have specified the Foreground, Background and BrushThickness to look properly as on W8, but on W7 these settings seem to be ignored.

I've also tried including the PresentationFramework.Aero2 but that makes it run on windows 8 and not windows 7. Selecting the Copy Local property on the reference did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because WPF on windows 7 and windows8 use different style by default. You have only 2 option but both will not satisfy you probably:

- Define a custom style for every control you are going to use
- Use a library like [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/) to develop your app.

I would suggest you to go with the second option. Your app should look the same(more or less) on both the environment